# set sshd SELinux security context

Tags: embedded, sshd, pam, selinux, audit

I'm working on my custom board and on my custom UNIX-like O.S. . When I connect using ssh and no root users a receve this SELinux error: A valid context for  could not be obtained. where user is not root user. On my log I read

```
pam_selinux(sshd:session): Unable to get valid context for user
ssh_selinux_getctxbyname: Failed to get default SELinux security
ssh_selinux_getctxbyname: Failed to get default SELinux security
ssh_selinux_setup_pty: security_compute_relabel: Invalid argument
```

and on my shell I read `Unable to get valid context for user`.

So: I think that is a  `/usr/sbin/sshd` SELinux context and it which is a wrong labeled. Running  `sestatus -v` from no root user I read:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          permissive
Policy MLS status:              disabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     denied
Memory protection checking:     actual (secure)
Max kernel policy version:      31

Process contexts:
Current context:                system_u:system_r:initrc_t
Init context:                   system_u:system_r:init_t

File contexts:
Controlling terminal:           system_u:object_r:initrc_devpts_t
/etc/passwd                     system_u:object_r:etc_t
/etc/shadow                     system_u:object_r:shadow_t
/bin/login                      system_u:object_r:login_exec_t
/bin/sh                         system_u:object_r:bin_t
/sbin/init                      system_u:object_r:init_exec_t
/usr/sbin/sshd                  system_u:object_r:root_t
/lib/libc.so.6                  system_u:object_r:lib_t -> system_u:object_r:lib_t
```

and running `id -Z` I get  `/usr/sbin/sshd   system_u:system_r:kernel_t` or  `system_u:system_r:initrc_t`. I tried to relabeled using `restorecon -v -r /*`  and `/usr/sbin/sshd`  process becames  `system_u:system_r:kernel_t`, while `/usr/sbin/sshd`  file context became  `system_u:system_r:bin_t`.

I think a good context for sshd could be `system_u:object_r:sshd_exec_t`. I tried to set it using chcon from root but when I run `id -Z` from no root user the context is not relabel and more, after reboot no root user sshd context became unlabeled.

On my system I cannot use semange program and I don't have "login boolean" to set. My getsebool -a list is very short.

In my `/etc/pam.d/sshd` configuration I have the following lines:

```
session    optional     /lib/security/pam_selinux.so close 
session    optional     /lib/security/pam_selinux.so multiple open
```

By removing the second line in pam configuration file above I get only the log error, but not console error. Alse removing both lines I get log and console errors. Why?

Can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: install `semanage-utils`

Comment: semanage was installed from my cross build environment but for some unknown reason it doesn't work. Is there another way to set a good context?

Comment: If you're brave, you can check the /etc/selinux/targeted files....

Comment: For me in the ```file_contexts:/usr/sbin/sshd -- system_u:object_r:sshd_exec_t:s0
file_contexts:/usr/sbin/gsisshd -- system_u:object_r:sshd_exec_t:s0``` even /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files and /etc/selinux/targeted/active directory

Comment: Sorry for the absence.  I tried to update sshd context in /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/file/file_contexts, adding lines above on the top of the file, but its doesn't work. When I restart the system therer are the same errors. Honestly, this setup is very difficult for me.